# Erro ao inserir elementos em um vetor - C++

Tags: array, c++

Estou tentando chamar a função `montVetorCodigo` e `montVetorPeca` detro de `main` porém já testei diversas formas para colocar os elementos de um arquivo TXT dentro de um vetor porém ele só armazena as colunas da última linha.

Existe outra forma para que possa inserir esses dados nos vetores correspondentes??

```
54 ARRUELA  
93 ABRACADEIRA 
55 PINO 
49 PORCA 
60 RELE 
30 DISJUNTOR 
27 FUSIVEL 
72 MOUSE 
40 LAMPADA 
14 TECLA 
21 CAIXA 
33 TAMPA 
76 INTERRUPTOR 
26 SOQUETE  
7 BASE
63 LAMINA  
50 PLACA 
31 TUBO 
17 LATERAL 
92 VIDEO 
11 PLUG 
36 CABO 
52 SUPORTE 
83 BOTAO 
22 PARAFUSO
```

O código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void montVetorCodigo(int *v, int n, int x);
void montVetorPeca(string *vP, int n, string y);
void showVetorCodigo(int *v, int n);
void showVetorPeca(string *v, int n);

int main()
{
    fstream arquivo;
    string sArqNome,sLinha,sCodigo,sPeca;
    int iCodigo,iQtdLinhas=0,n;
    char cOp;

    cout << "Entre com o nome do arquivo: ";
    cin >> sArqNome;
    arquivo.open(sArqNome);
    if (arquivo.is_open()){
        while(!arquivo.eof()){  // contar as linhas para definir n
            getline(arquivo,sLinha);
            iQtdLinhas++;
        }
        n = iQtdLinhas;
        int iVetorCodigo[n];
        string sVetorPeca[n];
        int iQtdLinhas=0;
        arquivo.clear();
        arquivo.seekg(ios::beg);
        while(!arquivo.eof()){  // montagem do vetor coletando dados das colunas
            getline(arquivo,sLinha);
            sCodigo = sLinha.substr(0,2);
            sPeca = sLinha.substr(2,14);
            iCodigo = stoi(sCodigo);  // transformar string para int
            sPeca.erase(remove(sPeca.begin(), sPeca.end(), ' '), sPeca.end());  // remover espaços em branco da captura da string 'sPeca'
            cout << iCodigo << endl;
            cout << sPeca << endl;
            
            montVetorCodigo(iVetorCodigo,n,iCodigo);
            montVetorPeca(sVetorPeca,n,sPeca);
            iQtdLinhas++;
        }
        showVetorCodigo(iVetorCodigo,n);
        showVetorPeca(sVetorPeca,n);
    arquivo.close();
    return 0;
}

void montVetorCodigo(int *v, int n, int x){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        v[i] = x;
    }
}

void montVetorPeca(string *vP, int n, string y){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        vP[i] = y;
    }
}

void showVetorCodigo(int *v, int n){
    cout << "Indices:   ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << setw(3) << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Elementos: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << setw(3) << v[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void showVetorPeca(string *vP, int n){
    cout << "Indices:   ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << setw(3) << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Elementos: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << setw(3) << vP[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Mais especificamente nessa parte:

```
void montVetorCodigo(int *v, int n, int x){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        v[i] = x;
    }
}

void montVetorPeca(string *vP, int n, string y){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        vP[i] = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloca o conteúdo do arquivo que você está lendo no post tbm, pra galera poder testar.

Comment: Como você está tratando linha a linha do arquivo então deve inserir uma única posição em seu array e não inserir o mesmo valor em todas as posições. Creio que na chamada da função no lugar de `n` deveria informar `iQtdLinhas`, a posição aonde será colocado o código ou nome da peça.

Answer (score 1):

Se você precisa realmente das funções como declaradas e os dados nesse formato, acho que o simples é usar `fscanf()` para consumir a entrada e criar os dois vetores, mais ou menos como fez.

No entanto como escreveu está errado. `int*` e `int[]` são coisas diferentes e precisa construir o vetor com cuidado. Se precisa mesmo escrever assim escreva de volta e te mostro como fazer no estilo C.

#### Vou te mostrar 3 outras maneiras de escrever, e uma quarta:

> Ao final acrescentei um exemplo para mostrar como poderia fazer em
> tradicional C-style, assim terá algo mais completo

- usando um mapa: assim tem a vantagem de já entrar classificado e poder pesquisar pela peça direto numa única estrutura.
- usando dois vetores, mais ou menos como estava escrevendo em seu programa. Os valores ficam na ordem de entrada
- usando um vetor de pares, `int` e `string`, e assim você pode usar `sort()` para classificar o vetor. Veja no exemplo duas maneiras de usar sort, usando uma função comum para comparar ou usando uma função lambda, já que ela só tem uma linha afinal.

#### o arquivo de entrada

Para ficar mais fácil de ler usei apenas as primeiras 8 linhas do seu arquivo

```
54 ARRUELA  
93 ABRACADEIRA 
55 PINO 
49 PORCA 
60 RELE 
30 DISJUNTOR 
27 FUSIVEL 
72 MOUSE
```

#### Usando um mapa

```
Usando map<int><string>

id: 27 parte FUSIVEL
id: 30 parte DISJUNTOR
id: 49 parte PORCA
id: 54 parte ARRUELA
id: 55 parte PINO
id: 60 parte RELE
id: 72 parte MOUSE
id: 93 parte ABRACADEIRA

Lista pecas com id entre 90 e 95 inclusive:

Id 90:  - - -
Id 91:  - - -
Id 92:  - - -
Id 93: ABRACADEIRA
Id 94:  - - -
Id 95:  - - -
```

#### o código

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const string padrao = "pec.txt";
    string arquivo{ padrao };
    if (argc > 1) arquivo = argv[1];

    cout << "\nUsando map<int><string>\n\n";
    int id;
    string part;
    ifstream entrada { arquivo };
    map<int, string> partes;

    while (!entrada.eof())
    {
        entrada >> id;
        entrada >> part;
        partes.insert(pair(id, part));
    };  // while()

    for (auto& parte : partes)
    {
        cout << "id: "    << parte.first
             << " parte " << parte.second << endl;
    };  // for()

    // mostra as pecas entre 90 e 95
    cout << "\nLista pecas com id entre 90 e 95 inclusive:\n\n";
    for (int p = 90; p < 96; p = p + 1)
    {
        cout << "Id " << p << ": " ;
        auto x = partes.find(p);
        if (x != partes.end())
            cout << x->second << endl;
        else
            cout << " - - -\n";
    }
    return 0;
    };
```

#### Usando dois vetores ou um vetor de pares

```
Usando dois vetores

id: 54 parte ARRUELA
id: 93 parte ABRACADEIRA
id: 55 parte PINO
id: 49 parte PORCA
id: 60 parte RELE
id: 30 parte DISJUNTOR
id: 27 parte FUSIVEL
id: 72 parte MOUSE

Usando um vetor de pares


vetor como criado

id: 54 parte ARRUELA
id: 93 parte ABRACADEIRA
id: 55 parte PINO
id: 49 parte PORCA
id: 60 parte RELE
id: 30 parte DISJUNTOR
id: 27 parte FUSIVEL
id: 72 parte MOUSE

Ordena o vetor


vetor ordenado

id: 27 parte FUSIVEL
id: 30 parte DISJUNTOR
id: 49 parte PORCA
id: 54 parte ARRUELA
id: 55 parte PINO
id: 60 parte RELE
id: 72 parte MOUSE
id: 93 parte ABRACADEIRA
```

#### O programa usando os vetores

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int     compara(pair<int,string>, pair<int, string>);
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const string padrao = "pec.txt";
    string arquivo{ padrao };
    if (argc > 1) arquivo = argv[1];

    cout << "\nUsando dois vetores\n\n";
    int id;
    string part;
    ifstream entrada{ arquivo };
    vector<int> vId{};
    vector<string> vPeca{};

    while (!entrada.eof())
    {
        entrada >> id;
        entrada >> part;
        vId.push_back(id);
        vPeca.push_back(part);
    };  // while()

    for (int i=0; i< vId.size(); i+=1)
    {
        cout << "id: " << vId[i]
            << " parte " << vPeca[i] << endl;
    };  // for()


    cout << "\nUsando um vetor de pares\n\n";
    vector< pair<int, string> > vCad_ordenado{};
    entrada.seekg(0, entrada.beg);
    while (!entrada.eof())
    {
        entrada >> id;
        entrada >> part;
        vCad_ordenado.push_back( pair(id,part) );
    };  // while()

    cout << "\nvetor como criado\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < vCad_ordenado.size(); i += 1)
    {
        cout << "id: " << vCad_ordenado[i].first
            << " parte " << vCad_ordenado[i].second << endl;
    };  // for()

    cout << "\nOrdena o vetor\n\n";
    sort(vCad_ordenado.begin(), vCad_ordenado.end(), compara );
    // alternativa para o sort sem escrever a funcao de comparacao
    //sort(vCad_ordenado.begin(), vCad_ordenado.end(),
    //    [](pair<int, string>A, pair<int, string>B){ return A.first < B.first; });

    cout << "\nvetor ordenado\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < vCad_ordenado.size(); i += 1)
    {
        cout << "id: " << vCad_ordenado[i].first
            << " parte " << vCad_ordenado[i].second << endl;
    };  // for()

    return 0;
};

// para o sort
int     compara(pair<int, string> A, pair<int, string> B)
{
    return A.first < B.first;
};
```

#### E usando int[] afinal?

Não acho que seja uma boa idéia se não está usando C, mas veja

#### a saida

```
Usando scanf(), malloc() e realloc() em C-style, mas seguro. Arquivo: 'pec.txt'

8 itens lidos [limite atual 50]
   1: 54 ARRUELA
   2: 93 ABRACADEIRA
   3: 55 PINO
   4: 49 PORCA
   5: 60 RELE
   6: 30 DISJUNTOR
   7: 27 FUSIVEL
   8: 72 MOUSE
```

#### Deste programa

```
#define _BLOCO_ 50

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void montVetorCodigo(int* v, int n, int x);
void montVetorPeca(string* vP, int n, string y);
void showVetorCodigo(int* v, int n);
void showVetorPeca(string* v, int n);

typedef struct
{
    unsigned    limite; // tamanho alocado
    unsigned    N; // total de pecas
    int**       id; // codigo
    char**      peca; // nome

}   Cadastro;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const string padrao = "pec.txt";
    string arquivo{ padrao };
    if (argc > 1) arquivo = argv[1];

    cout << "\nUsando scanf(), malloc() e realloc() em C-style, mas seguro. Arquivo: '"
        << arquivo << "'\n\n";

    // o estoque comeca vazio e com um bloco de ponteiros
    // para nao ficar alocando toda hora
    Cadastro estoque;
    estoque.limite = _BLOCO_;
    estoque.N = 0;
    estoque.id =   (int**) malloc(_BLOCO_ * sizeof(*estoque.id));
    estoque.peca = (char**) malloc(_BLOCO_ * sizeof(*estoque.peca));

    ifstream entrada{ arquivo };
    string uma;
    Cadastro* C = &estoque; // mais curto pra escrever
    while (!entrada.eof())
    {
        C->id[C->N] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
        entrada >> *C->id[C->N];
        entrada >> uma; // uma peca
        C->peca[C->N] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(uma.length() + 1));
        // copia a string para o novo lar
        strcpy(C->peca[C->N], uma.c_str());
        C->N += 1;

        // agora se gastou o ultimo lugar do bloco alocado 
        // precisa aumentar o bloco
        if (C->N == C->limite)
        {
            C->limite += _BLOCO_; // aumenta
            int* novo = (int*)realloc(C->id, C->limite * sizeof(int*));
            if (novo == NULL) return -1;
            C->id = (int**)novo;
            char * nova = (char*)realloc(C->peca, C->limite * sizeof(char*));
            if (novo == NULL) return -2;
            C->peca = (char**)nova;
        }
    };  // while()

    // leu tudo 

    cout << C->N << " itens lidos [limite atual " <<
        C->limite << "]\n";

    // mostra o estoque

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < C->N; i += 1)
    {
        cout << setw(4) << 1+i << ": " << *C->id[i]
            << " " << C->peca[i] << "\n";
    };  // for
    return 0;
    }
```

Note que em todos esses exemplos pode usar o nome do arquivo na linha de comando

```
    programa [arquivo]
```

Ao invés de compilar o programa de novo só porque vai usar outro arquivo de entrada